# Were 14 US-Led Coalition Military Advisors captured by Syrian Special Forces in Aleppo?

Tags: united-states, media, syria

It caught my eye on Wikipedia's current events portal that US-led coalition military advisors had been captured in a bunker in Aleppo. This story has since disappeared off of Wikipedia, but several (off-beat and minor) news sites are reporting it. For instance [Fourteen US-Led Coalition Military Advisers Captured by Syrian Forces in Aleppo](http://www.globalresearch.ca/breaking-fourteen-us-led-coalition-military-advisers-captured-by-syrian-forces-in-aleppo/5563139) at Globalsearch.ca.

No major news outlet seems to be reporting it.

Is it fake or merely unverified?

Comment: Another site says 22 US, 16 UK, 21 French, 7 Israeli, 62 Turkish, and possibly some Moroccan (I don't understand what it means about Moroccans). http://www.veteranstoday.com/2016/12/17/breaking-syrian-special-forces-captured-14-us-coalition-officers-captured-in-aleppo/ and says " they were not really 'captured' but were allowed out as part of a deal between all parties involved".

Comment: @DavePhD strange